# WCF Service Causes SQL Deadlock Error

Tags: sql, wcf, asynchronous, dynamics-crm-2011, deadlock

I have been beating my head against the wall with this for the last couple days and I can’t seem to come up with a good solution.

I have a WCF service that acts as the only entry point with all of our database interactions. In the current dilemma, there is a Windows Service that spins against an “AsyncOperation” table within the Microsoft Dynamics CRM. Whenever an entity record is created in the CRM the windows service picks up the record out of the AsyncOperation table and fires a request off to the WCF service with that data. The issue I’m running into is that when that Windows Service fires off multiple requests simultaneously to the WCF service, the service causes a transaction deadlock in SQL.

I added some additional logging to the data flow within the WCF service and I found that at any given time anywhere from 3 – 5 requests could hit the service within milliseconds of each other. It seems that in the process the first request that hits the service is the only one to make it into the database, the rest end up causing a sql deadlock error:

> Transaction (Process ID 95) was deadlocked on lock resources with
>   another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the
>   transaction.

My question is this: Is there a good way to implement sometime of queuing process or singleton approach to WCF that will ensure SQL inserts aren’t happening at exactly the same time?  Since I’m building on top of the MS Dynamics platform I don’t have a way to ensure multiple requests aren’t processed at the same time. The data that is fed into the system is provided from external partners and some of them hit our system fairly heavy.

I’m open to any suggestions where I could look into finding a solution.

The method in the WCF service that handles the insert is this:

```
public List<NoelGroup.Users.Core.Entity.BusinessLayer.PersonEntity> Insert(NoelGroup.Users.Core.Entity.BusinessLayer.PersonEntity businessObject)
{
    List<NoelGroup.Users.Core.Entity.BusinessLayer.PersonEntity> businessObjectList = null;

    using (SqlConnection conn = MainConnection)
    {
        int id = new Random().Next(9999);
        try
        {
            conn.Open();

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[crud].[usp_Person_InsertUpdate]", conn))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@iui_PersonId", businessObject.PersonId));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ii_PrefixId", businessObject.PrefixId));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ivn_FirstName", businessObject.FirstName));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ivn_MiddleName", businessObject.MiddleName));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ivn_LastName", businessObject.LastName));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ic_Gender", businessObject.Gender));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ii_SuffixId", businessObject.SuffixId));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ii_PersonTypeId", businessObject.PersonTypeId));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id_BirthDate", businessObject.BirthDate));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@iti_PreferredContactMethodId", businessObject.PreferredContactMethodId));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@iv_ModifiedUsername", businessObject.ModifiedUsername));

                Logger.Log(string.Format("-- PersonEntity Insert ({1}) Execute -- {0}", DateTime.Now, id));
                using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    businessObject = null;
                    businessObject = new NoelGroup.Users.Core.Entity.BusinessLayer.PersonEntity();

                    businessObjectList = PopulateObjectsFromReader(rdr);
                }
                Logger.Log(string.Format("-- PersonEntity Insert ({1}) Complete -- {0}", DateTime.Now, id));
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw new SeverityException(500, string.Format("PersonEntity::Insert ({0})::Error occured.", id), ex);
            //throw new SeverityException(500, "PersonEntity::Insert::Error occured.", ex);
        }
    }

    return businessObjectList;
}
```

Comment: Is your WCF Service load balanced as well?

Comment: initially it was going to be, by nature of pass through proxies via WSO2 esb. but we ran into some network traffic issues on the ESB so we are postponing that implementation. As of now, it is only strait calls to the WCF service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should review the stored procedures that you use in order not to generate the deadlocks. Sql is intended to work in parallel with multiple requests. There are ways to review the code and improve so that you do not get into deadlocks.

If this is not a possibility you could use the service broker to queue your requests to the sql server (if you use a version of sql server that supports it). That means that you have to check later for the result of your operation.

If still this is not the case (ms-sql <2005) then you can implement something similar. Write your request to a table and use a job to deal with it. And again check later for the result of the operation.

In case you can use CLR stored procedures, you can call your WCF service with the result of the operation, so that you will not need to check the DB periodically.

Hope this helps.

As an edit, you can also check for the deadlock in your SP and retry in case that error comes up (check for error no 1205)

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful. The CLR approach is really cool, but I think it might be a bit overkill for what we're trying to do. I'm going to take a look at the stored procedures and see if they can be optimized a bit better.

Comment: i resolved the deadlock issue by wrapping the operations in the stored proc within a try/catch that had retry logic if the error was a deadlock. I'm a novice a sql, so this slipped by me
http://www.dwdmbi.com/2012/01/deadlock-recovery-using-try-catch-in.html